# Summation of elements of a matrix in matrix notation

Tags: matrices, summation, trace

I have come across the following proof in a research paper. I feel the given end formula is wrong.

Any help to correct it is greatly appreciated.

[image]

where $V = \{v_{ij}\} \hspace{0.3cm} \text{with} \hspace{0.3cm} v_{ij}=\sqrt{w}_{ij}$.